# Masonry with Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, masonry

When I load the page, the grid looks like this:

[image]

Only when I re-size the screen (I drag the border left and then right) it looks ok:
[image]

This is my code in my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item" v-for="(data, index) in data" :key="index">
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'painting', params: { id: index } }">
        <img v-bind:src="publicURL + data.images.thumbnail.substring(1)" />
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import data from "../assets/data.json";

export default {
  name: "Galleria",
  components: {},
  created() {
    this.publicURL = "https://6e222.csb.app";
  },
  mounted() {
    let grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
    this.msnry = new Masonry(grid, {
      columnWidth: 25,
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      data: data,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is because height of Yours blocks depends of height of images
on first case masonry try to read height of elements and get only padding value

you need to wait for the images to load

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).